# How to properly parse a JSON table for use in a Value function?

Tags: json, lua, roblox

I have failed miserably several times to use httpservice to successfully draw information off of my server for use in my Roblox game I am working on. After a number of failed efforts, I discovered that the main problem was I am failing to parse the table to get the value I need from the JSON table and that is, I think, why I can't get the Currency Handler script to accept the value.

I have an Ubuntu server service and something called Putty to access it.

I have done enough trial and error to believe that the handler script is working as intended except for not receiving the information from the next script correctly.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local value = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    value.Name = "Currency"
    value.Value = 0
    
    local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
    local userID = '0' --player.UserId
    local wallet = "http://x8/"


    local mining = wallet..userID
    local response = HttpService:GetAsync(mining, HttpService:JSONDecode(), Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson)
    local a,b,c,d = table.remove(response)
    local function f()
        value.Value = 1
    
    end

    
end)
```

I also have a localscript running that looks like this.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

player:WaitForChild("Currency").changed:Connect(function(value)
    script.Parent.Currency.Text = "D "..value
end)

script.Parent.Currency.Text = "D "..player:WaitForChild("Currency").Value
```

This is after reading the various manuals from Piglet.

I am not a professional programmer or software engineer. I don't really know much about programming except what I have been able to glean from youtube and a few online tutorials. I've come as far as I can with those resources. The irony is I think this should be my last major hurdle to accomplishing my goals of getting a working Roblox game. I've used Wiki, and Roblox developer forums, but I don't fully understand them.

Comment: what is the purpose of the last few lines? I cannot make sense of it.  a json decode function ususally turns a json string into a table. it should usually complain about you putting a table into it. also you're not doing anythign with the results of all your operations so I'm wondering what you thought would happen here. please add a few comments

Comment: What are you trying to do in the 2nd snippet? I don't know what ``local t`` is supposed to represent, neither its purpose.

What data does ``response`` give, and what is its significance?

Comment: You could try to explain to yourself the meaning and effect of every line of the second script. Just so you fully understand what is happening. Piglet is right, it should crash, decode expects a json string.

Comment: I would love to be able to explain to myself the code, but I don't know what any of it means. My problem is I am looking at tutorials and trying to find stuff from those tutorials that I think might work. I really don't know what any of it does or means. What I want to do is take the JSON from the server and parse out the amount which is the last element in that string.

Comment: What I thought I was doing with everything in the last line of code was telling the JSON function to put the information into that table. I can look at the info on the server, but I don't know how to parse, and I can't find how to grab one element from a JSON when all I want is the last piece of info on that.

Comment: That's fine, but where is the manual then?

Comment: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/HttpService   read this, compare the code example vs what you're doing.  if you're using a function, make sure you know what it does and how its parameters affect the outcome

if you're looking for a manual for let's say roblox, simply google "roblox manual"  and just in case:  https://luau-lang.org/syntax  and   https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.

Comment: I had already read the roblox manual, but the second and third link are actually more helpful to me.

Comment: don't have yourself being discouraged. reading manuals is just so important for every programmer and there is very little room for guess work in this domain. if you make it a habit to refer to a manual for everything you don't know or are unsure about you'll drastically increase your progress over time. you need a for loop? read everything about it. want to use json? make sure you at least read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON , ensure you know the difference betwen decode and encode,... doing a HTTP request? read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: And as screwed up as I have the program I showed, it doesn't make much difference because there is a gui localscript that I can't change even with a simple `value.Value = value.Value +1` function inside the script above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate a table using the code above, but the table.remove is still not working. I will attempt to correct that problem, and this is the code I came up with

```
        local mining = wallet..userID
        local response
        local data
        
        response = HttpService:GetAsync(mining)
        data = HttpService:JSONDecode(response, Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson)
    local a = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    
    
    a = (data["result"]["amount"])
    
    
    
    print(data["result"]["amount"])

    print(a)
    
    
        value.Value = a
        print(value.Value)
        return value
        end)
```

not sure if this was the right way to do things, but it worked.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what ``data`` or ``response`` would look like in your case? I don't think [``table.remove(yourTableHere, Position)``](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/lua-docs/table#:~:text=table.remove) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Solution has been changed fairly radically.

Comment: I believe you do not need to create a NumberValue. You could simply just do ``local a = data.result.amount``. Also [HttpService:JSONDecode(jsonText)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/HttpService/JSONDecode) has 1 parameter, so remove ``Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson`` (how it was earlier).